# How do you create a class in Wollok?

Tags: oop, wollok

I want to know if it's possible to define a class with some sort of constructor or if I have to initialize every field by hand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Constructors in wollok are defined using the 'constructor' keyword. For example:

```
class Point {
    var x
    var y

    constructor(_x, _y) {
        x = _x
        y = _y
    }
}
```